# why a cookie deleting in mobile application?

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc, react-native, cookies, autofill

We were created a web application, its working fine.  and after we created  a mobile application based this application with react native. Everything is fine but we have some problem with our cookies in all mobile devices. (ios and android)

Cookie is working fine on web. There is no problem. But in mobile application we lost our cookies and its not depends on time. Sometimes it takes 5 minutes, sometimes 1 hours even Expire time is 1 year.

our login and logout method

```
        public async Task SetAuthCookie(User user, bool rememberMe)
    {
        _authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        _authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        var identity = await _userManager.CreateIdentityAsync(user, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
        _authenticationManager.SignIn(new AuthenticationProperties {IsPersistent = rememberMe, ExpiresUtc=DateTime.UtcNow.AddYears(1) }, identity);
    }

    public void Logout()
    {
        _authenticationManager.SignOut(DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie);
    }
```

and the other problem is; I cant see old e-mail adresses when click e-mail adress in login form. Autofill is not working correctly. I can see autofill (old emails) only when i close the keyboards. I think its about the 'Autofill' position but i dont know how can i change the autofill position.

The both problem is in my mobile application. there is no problem on browsers .

I would like to ask some question about this problem.
why i lost my cookies? 
why its deleting? 
and my application doesnt remember me and how can i solve this autofill problem on login from?

if you want i can share my login form.

Thanks!

Comment: the autofill "problem" has everything to do with the browser and nothing to with `asp.net`. unless you are trying to fill-in the username and password using `javascript`..

Comment: thanks, and yes its a normal razor page. i am not using javascript for login.

Comment: ok, so make sure that autofill is enabled on your browser and/or try different browsers

Comment: this problem is only in my mobile application. On browsers everything is fine.

Comment: What kind of mobile application? Do you mean a mobile browser? Like chrome for android?

Comment: its a mobile application  which created with react native. Everything is fine when i login in chrome or another browsers.